# Homotopy class of a path in a Klein Bottle with two points removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, klein-bottle

[Klein Bottle with two points removed and path $\alpha$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNA2X.jpg)

Hi guys, I'm trying to calculate the homotopy class of path $\alpha$ in the Klein Bottle with points Q and R removed (picture above). For now I've managed to show that this space is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$.

My question is if it's possible to calculate it easely just looking at the square rapresenting the space (knowing its Fundamental Group's generators) or if it's easier to draw the entire space and proceed in a more "intuitive" way.

(I've basic notions of Algebraic Topology, Van Kampen's theorem is the most advanced result I've seen)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How (explicitly) have you proven that the space is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$? What is the image of $\alpha$ under this homotopy equivalence?

Comment: I did it intuitively: I've introduced a new path named "delta" connecting  the "opposite sides" b and b in order to cut in half the square and "separate" the missing points R and Q.  Then i've radially projected each half toward a,b and delta. Maybe if do the same reasoning using "alpha" instead of "delta" i can easily say that the image of "alpha" under the homotopy equivalence is just "alpha".

Comment: If you can turn that intuitive proof into an actual proof, for example by embedding $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1 \hookrightarrow K - \{Q,R\}$ as a deformation retract, then you should be able to do this easily.